# SQL remove and filter similar results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query which gives me a list of orders where an address comes up twice so we can double pack same orders to the same address

```
select * from Orders
where 
address in (select address from orders group by address having count(*) = 2)




CustID     StockID      Address             Company 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1217        23185       1 Some Road         Stockton            
58458       23185       1 Some Road                     
58459       23185       4 John St                       
58457       23185       4 John St                       
299576      23185       9 Roadway PDE       Graceland           
59470       23185       9 Roadway PDE       Cahill Tow          
97656       23185       24 Kent St                      
97677       23185       24 Kent St                      
212732      23185       23 Best Rd                      
226583      23185       23 Best Rd          c/o John            
191718      23185       98 King St                      
156363      23185       98 King St                      
121106      23185       19 Broadway                     
156362      23185       19 Broadway
```

I want the result to look like this which excludes any addresses which come up which have a company name in either of the 2 results that come up for it. Some addresses have nothing in the Company name however i want to exclude them as well if the other result for the same address contains a company name.

```
CustID     StockID      Address             Company 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
58459       23185       4 John St                       
58457       23185       4 John St                       
97656       23185       24 Kent St                      
97677       23185       24 Kent St                      
191718      23185       98 King St                      
156363      23185       98 King St                      
121106      23185       19 Broadway                     
156362      23185       19 Broadway
```

Hope this all makes sense and appreciate any help

Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to add a `WHERE` clause in your subquery.  Note that unless you've done some form of address canonicalization, different forms of the same address may slip through (ie, `N.E.` vs `NE`, `AVE` vs `Ave`, etc).  I might also add a filter to only do this if the _customer_ is the same - what about the case of people in dorms, shared housing, etc?

Comment: exactly my problem im trying to solve, i just want to remove any of the lines which contain a company which also belong to the same address. So shared dorms can also be included in the company name if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from Orders o1
where 
0 = (select count(*) from orders o2 
     where o1.address = o2.address 
     and company is not null)`

 This is a correlated sub-query which ties the main query and subquery together over address. I have assumed "empty" company is `NULL`, replace with `<> ""` if you don't use nulls.

Comment: thanks @Turophile i think this is the correct query and gives me the results i need the only thing i needed to do is replace company is not null with company <> '' and it gives me what i need. THANK YOU!!

Also is there a way to join this with my original query of having count=2? or can i only do this using a temp database?

Comment: What do you mean by join the queries? Please put it in a clear sentence like: "All rows where there is more than one order for the same address AND there is no company on any of the rows for the address"

Comment: No worries..so my initial query is "select * from Orders
where 
address in select address from orders group by address having count(*) = 2)" How can i use your sub-query to make this all one query?

Comment: Actually no need, i managed to figure it out. thank you once again @Turophile

Answer (score 0):

AS @ClockWork-Muse mentions in the comments, there's a lot of things you need to consider in this scenario, pertaining to data cleanliness as well as business logic. Having said that, you can try this for your issue:

```
;with filtered as
(
select * from Orders
where 
address in (select address from orders group by address having count(*) = 2)
)
,cte as
(select address, max(company) as max
from filtered
group by address
having max(company) = '')
select f.* from filtered f
inner join cte c on f.address = c.address
```

Basically, you create a CTE to identify those companies which have only blank values for `Company`, and then join back to the results of your query

Comment: Thanks for the answer @shree.pat18 but this gives me lower results than expected, thank Turophile's query which returns the correct number of results.